# Typescript: Using RegExp for type keys

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use a regex as a key property?

The use case here is that I'm getting data that must have position information (latitude & longitude) but I don't care about capitalization.

Ideally, I could declare something like this:

```
interface HasPosition {
   [lat: /latitude/i]: number;
   [lng: /longitude/i]: number;
}
```

Both `{ latitude: 23.5, longitude: 34.5 }` and `{ LATITUDE: 23.5, LongITUDe: 34.5 }` would be type `HasPosition`.

Is this doable? It seems possibly related to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579) (since I'm essentially trying to validate the strings that are a datapoint's keys). I've tried a lot of things that end up being non-sense syntax (including the code above), so I'm open to other types of solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You said `I'm open to other types of solutions`, so I think one way is use custom mapper to convert object to `HasPosition` interface.

Something like this:

```
class Utils {
    static MapToPosition(obj: object) : HasPosition 
    {
      var position :HasPosition =  {lat:0, lng:0};
      (Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>).forEach(t=>{
           if((t as string).toLowerCase().includes("latitude"))
               position["lat"] = obj[t];
            else if((t as string).toLowerCase().includes("longitude"))
               position["lng"]= obj[t];
      })
     return position;
    }
}

var pos1 = Utils.MapToPosition({ latitude: 23.5, longitude: 34.5 });
var pos2 = Utils.MapToPosition({ LATITUDE: 23.5, LongITUDe: 34.5 });
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=69&pln=5&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBJwM4AUD2HhjA4jIDeAUMlQDZxgBcyIArgLYBG0A3JTSAOaMWHbuQC%205BLQwZkAVULVZFKlQxg6wBMgCycAA4AVHLnyFiAChzsAVo2s2ICMAEpkjdNjwEiJXlRVVKgA3OChkfW9zEnpPUx9iZABeANoGAAYAGmRqAXp0sR4gqgsAeVsnMAA6AGsIAE8MK1s3TGQAQSgoOHqAHjr6nBhkMHr9CCHkBwA%20FyqYHCgAUUQACwswJOnA4qDgGAsN5Db1KFB%20ObAcABkcAHdoAGFMCAs50ClmABMIJoAiNIEb4QP4uFz%20Xa7SJmXwAbQBdD%20AF1klNbLCwEiipCghAlCh9ocwMdZKdzpcbvcni83lUPtRgf9qMR%20ECfqDwTjIdCEiB4bl%20MiUg4MViIVQxJyglAIGBmFASDzotiJeJyORQuFoQBGVEKYBKKp6IwmKK%20CykHKaOU-RgAJgAzFUAKzZZkCNkQRgOgAsLuQkp4moieDtesUGCNBmM8WiFuQ13ahgAkoY5AARJb2p2uhMs1MZr3IX3%20wPqhDEDA4agQKrM-gWHV1uguHgVkBVmt1nAN6F2usCVvkIA)